# Fac acronym in the Mix tab

Tags: node-editor

What does **Fac** in the *Mix* tab stand for (in the golden tab *Mix* below ) ? I cannot find it in the Manual.

[image]

Comment: *"Controls the amount of influence the node exerts on the output image."* - from: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html

Comment: You mean mix factor?

Comment: Why are you using vector curves for black and white information like a mask?

Comment: @susu I'm just experimenttig to see what I get with vector curves.

Comment: @susu Please, what is the difference between adding a source to **Fac** and to **Image** to a **Mix** node ?

Comment: @brockmann Please, what is the difference between adding a source to **Fac** and to **Image** to a **Mix** node ?

Comment: @user2925716 please,  ask new questions on  a different post! not as comments.

Comment: And please refer to the **blender manual** as well, most of the questions you've been asking are already explained there: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fac. is short for **Factor**

Nodes that have such input can use scalar information, or a grayscale image, as values to control the mix between two different elements.